# How to run flask and discord bot simultaneously on heroku?

Tags: flask, heroku, discord.py

I have tried this code on my localhost with command `python main.py`, it works

main.py

```
import asyncio
import app
import mybot

app.run_async() #async run flask app

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

loop.create_task(mybot.bot.start(BOT_TOKEN))
loop.run_forever()
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'hello world'

def run_server():
    app.run()

def run_async():
    server = Thread(target=run_server)
    server.daemon = True
    server.start()
```

mybot.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands

class Bot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        intents = discord.Intents.all()
        super().__init__(command_prefix = "!",
                         intents = intents,
                         help_command=None
                         )
    
    async def setup_hook(self) -> None:
        await self.tree.sync(guild = discord.Object(id = GUILD_ID))
        print(f"Now login user: {self.user}.")
bot = Bot()

@bot.hybrid_command(name = "ping", with_app_command = True, description = "pong")
@app_commands.guilds(discord.Object(id = GUILD_ID))
async def ping(ctx: commands.Context):
    await ctx.defer(ephemeral = True)
    await ctx.reply("pong!")
```

But if I set Procfile like `web: gunicorn app:app` and deploy on heroku, the discord bot dosen't work

if I set Procfile like `web: python3 main.py`, the web dosen't work.

How do I make them work simultaneously?

I've tried doing this on render.com and it works. But I can't do it on heroku.

Comment: why would you want that? it's better to keep it separate, it's two completely different apps, they aren't supposed to be ran together.